# How to create a C++ web-service which can be consumed by any website?

Tags: c++, multithreading, web-services

I have some c++ code (which does some task on desktop). I want to use this C++ code in my web-site and as I am planning to improve this code by adding some more function so It can be converted to any other language like C# or java.

So here are main things I want to do:

- How to use C++ code in a website?
- How this C++ code can be build as a web service to provide multi-threading and can response parallel to each and every request comes from client side?

Can somebody guide me how to do this?

Comment: Use dynamic library and place all needed functions there. When you do your web-service, just use the library. You can call these functions from any thread you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the question does not fit to SO standards, but let's try to answer.

If your C++ code uses some of the platform specific calls, then you have to use the same platform. It's not likely that Windows application will work under Unix, unless it's trivial. Still, there are no guarantees that some of the desktop features can be ran as web service. For instance, application with GUI cannot be (in a straight forward manner) started as a web service.

If the code is generic in a way that contains logic that is runnable both as desktop and web application, then it should be encapsulated by the web server.

Some of the options:

- Run a web server like Apache and use [C++ server pages](http://www.micronovae.com/CSP.html), so you could embed your C++ logic.
- Create your own web server by using threads and sockets. This approach assumes you know how to build from the scratch, so you should get a tutorial on networking. There are libraries like [Poco](http://pocoproject.org) that encapsulate some of that logic into classes, and provide server classes to be extended with your logic.
- There are other approaches like using [gSOAP](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html), [Ice](https://zeroc.com/products/ice), Apache Axis, XML-RPC... Each of them gives a layer of abstraction, so depending of your needs, you can select one or another.

In total, if you want to deal with networking details on your own, then go with learning sockets/threads, but it takes a time. If you want to make a work done, use some of the existing frameworks.

Comment: CSP(C++ Server Pages) is designed for Windows Server 2000, and Windows Server 2003 on 32bit platforms. It does not work on any other operating system than Windows 2000/2003 Server.

Comment: @Mavie: What are your requirements? Anyway, the question is broad to come with the more specific answer. There are a lot of methods to accomplish your task.

Comment: Thanks for responding ! I have some C++ code which I want to use on my web site. To do this I created COM DLL for C++ code and used it in C# Web site but as It provides multi-threading but process was executing each request one by one means each request have to wait for previous request to complete. So It was not parallel execution. I want to use my code in My website.

Comment: I am not sure that I am following you. Is it the requirement to run the code in parallel or to be used on your website? Anyway, it does not have to be the case that your code is ready to be run in parallel in either of these cases. As said, the question cannot be answered if asked this way.